# How to compute $J_{\varepsilon}=\int_{B(0, \varepsilon)^c}\Phi(y)\Delta_yf(x-y)dy$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

In Evans' textbook PDE P24: Theorem 1(Solving Poisson's equation)

I am confused with the computation in the $\Delta u$:

$$\Delta u=\int_{B(0, \varepsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_xf(x-y)dy+\int_{B(0, \varepsilon)^c}\Phi(y)\Delta_xf(x-y)dy\\:=I_{\varepsilon}+J_{\varepsilon}$$

For the $J_{\varepsilon}$, 
***Q(1): why we can get the integral***

> $$J_{\varepsilon}=\int_{B(0, \varepsilon)^c}\Phi(y)\Delta_yf(x-y)dy\\=-\int_{B(0, \varepsilon)^c}D\Phi(y)\cdot D_y f(x-y)dy+\int_{\partial B(0, \varepsilon)}\Phi(y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial \nu}(x-y)dS(y)\\:=K_{\varepsilon}+L_{\varepsilon}$$
>   where $\nu$ denoting the inward pointing unit normal along $\partial B(0, \varepsilon)$

***Q(2): why we can get the integral of $K_{\varepsilon}$ as following:***

> $$K_{\varepsilon}=\int_{B(0, \varepsilon)^c}\Delta\Phi(y)f(x-y)dy-\int_{\partial B(0, \varepsilon)}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \nu}(y)f(x-y)dS(y)$$

I know that I should use the divergence theorem: 
$$\int_{B_{n+1}(0, R)}\partial_{x_{n+1}}f(x)dx=\int_{\partial B_{n+1}(0, R)}f(x)\nu_{n+1}dS(x)$$
and integral by part.

But I feel that 
$$J_{\varepsilon}=\int_{\partial B(0, \varepsilon)^c}\Phi(y)D_xf(x-y)d\Gamma-\int_{B(0, \varepsilon)^c}D\Phi(y)\cdot D_x f(x-y)dy$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $J_{\epsilon}$ , First the Laplacian is converted from $\Delta_x$ to $\Delta_y$, basically its easy to see that $\nabla_x$ = -$\nabla_y$, then for the laplacian the negatives cancel and you get that the Laplacian in either variable is equal.

Next instead of using the divergence theorem, Use the following form of Greenes first identity

$\int_{U}Dv\cdot Du\,dx = -\int_{U}u\Delta v\,dx +\int_{\partial{U}}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}u\,dS$

both integrals of $K_\epsilon$ and $J_\epsilon$ follow from this

Hope his helps!